Can I feed my saltwater snails spirulina powder?
I am surprised this hasn't been asked on here yet but I cannot find any answers. I know that my carnivorous snails (my Nassarius) must eat meat but can I feed everybody else Spirulina? Uncertain what species they are, but maybe Nerite or Margarite and an Astraea???
I used to have the tank with a brine shrimp but now its just snails and I want to ensure enough food.
Are there any other nutrients I must give them?
I have heard some folks feeding their snails calcium and was uncertain if this was necessary to be mixed in (or if it is already in the sea water). Thank you so much for any help you can provide.
